# How to develop a wacom driver for linux?

Tags: linux, wacom

I am going to read absolute position from touchpad ,and the simulate a wacom so that oridinary applications like GIMP can be adapted.

I have successfully get absolute position from my touchpad,but where can I get the document on developing a fake wacom driver.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing, but start with the actual Wacom Linux driver, and change what you need from that: https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom